# My kid wants to be a pilot

Tags: flight-training

My 7 yo is really keen on taking up aviation as a career.

I have seen multiple times where kids at the age of 15-16 get licenses to fly. How does that happen?

Looking for some advise on how to start this journey for my little man?

Comment: Assuming this is in the US, find a flight school, go on a discovery flight (yes, even at 7 years old). Be prepared to open your wallet. In the US you must be 16 to solo, but you can fly a glider solo at 14.

Comment: If you are in the US there is also the Civil Air Patrol in a few years.

Comment: There is also the Experimental Aircraft Association. They take kids as young a eight years old on a type of discovery flight so that they can get their first experiences in aviation through their Young Eagles program. They also give each participant access to a free online ground school. Flight training scholarships and internships are also available. https://youngeaglesday.org/

Answer (score 5):

The following information is based on US FAA regulations and training programs.

In the US, there is no age limit (minimum or maximum) you must be in order to fly at the controls of an aircraft. There are age limits specified in Title 14 of the Code of Federal Regulations Part 61. Here are some of the particulars:

- 14 or older to solo a ballon or glider.
- 16 or older to get a balloon or glider private pilot certificate.
- 16 or older to solo a powered aircraft.
- 17 or older to get a powered aircraft private pilot certificate.
- 18 or older to get a commercial pilot certificate.

In the meantime, you can get your child into one of several youth aviation programs like Civil Air Patrol, or the Young Eagles.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe start him with balsa/foam gliders that will help him learn about the basics of flight (lift, balance, etc). Toys are kid-friendly versions of things in the world, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the US, I have seen several kids solo in gliders at 14 years of age and get their private glider rating at 16 years of age.  Glider training is really good training.  Glider clubs vary wildly in terms of annual dues and rates for air time and tows.  Some are amazingly affordable, others are not.  Some have scholarships available to subsidize flight training for youth.  Commercial operations will always cost more, but require less investment in time.  Some research into what glider clubs are available to you within a reasonable driving distance, may really pay off.  There's not much point in starting this training more than a year or two before your son's 14th birthday.

When your kid is of an appropriate age, keep an eye out for any "Explorer" scout posts that exist in your area, with a focus on aviation.  Sometimes these units offer ground school courses, opportunities for flight experiences, etc.

Until then, in terms of just "stoking the fires" and exploring the general principles of flight, radio-controlled airplanes are great way to go, especially once your son gets to be around 11 to 13 years old.  The advent of airplanes made of EPP foam or other similar foams has brought about a whole new world in terms of crash-resistance and ease of repairs.  Don't start with something too exotic.  Something like the [HobbyZone Super Cub](https://www.horizonhobby.com/product/super-cub-s-1.2m-rtf-with-safe/HBZ8100E.html) is a great way to go.  It is very crashworthy due to its small size and light weight and mostly-solid-foam forward fuselage.  And many hobby stores carry individual parts such as motor, gearbox, wings, etc, for quick and inexpensive replacement.  The lack of ailerons are not a big issue-- you or your kid can always add them later.  Another way to go that might be suitable for a slightly younger age is a very light, small plane designed to fly indoors, such as the Eflite or Parkzone ["Vapor"](https://www.towerhobbies.com/product/umx-night-vapor-bnf-basic-with-as3x-and-safe-select-376mm/EFLU1350.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA34OBBhCcARIsAG32uvPYtR5bPyzyQC2GUxssAuZBcIgWRmhHqsrRMN2-EfDWoUAmOsD0V3saAsc3EALw_wcB).

Before then?  Some good books about aviation history with lots of well-done illustrations can help keep your kid's interest fired up.  Among other things, check out the Time-Life series called "The Epic of Flight".  These books were printed decades ago but still should be of interest.  They can often be found in second-hand book stores.  And yes, as some other answers and comments have noted, be sure to check out the Experimental Aircraft Association's "Young Eagles" program-- its whole purpose is to allow young people to experience flight in a light aircraft.